# Finding name variations from large list Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript, mongoid5

I have a large list of words maybe 300-600 words and I want to make it so that as my user begins typing in a word the app suggest words that it found from my specific list that are close to the spelling that person is giving. Kind of like auto-complete but the list of words is dynamic and specific to that user. Any gems or techniques suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: One option is using [jQuery Autocomplete control](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/).

Comment: With a word list that short it probably makes sense to do it on the client-side, i.e. send the entire word list to the browser on page load (versus doing an Ajax request on every keystroke) and then use a component like [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) (or the jQuery plugin Nic mentioned) to handle the user interaction.

Comment: @Jordan even if it has to get the wordlist by going thru an array of objects and pulling the "name" characteristic from each object in the array?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the details of your implementation. You're going to have to do that work at some point, whether it's up-front on the server, up-front on the client, or partially on the server upon each keypress. I suggest doing whatever's simplest now and optimizing later if you run into performance problems. (typeahead.js, for its part, ought to work either way, as will many other such components.)

Comment: ok I think I will create the list in the action before loading the page, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in ruby you could use a fuzzy match algorithm, like the one used in this gem https://github.com/seamusabshere/fuzzy_match check the example:

```
>> FuzzyMatch.new(['seamus', 'andy', 'ben']).find('Shamus')
=> "seamus"
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try!